# Materialized view based on views and tables - how?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

We have a slow view that we wish to Materialize. The view depends on tables **and other views**.

Example structure:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE table2(id2 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
  SELECT id2 
  FROM table2;

CREATE VIEW view_to_materialize AS 
  SELECT id, id2 
  FROM table1 JOIN view1 (ON...);
```

We need a trigger to refresh the MV upon an insert/update/delete (let's call the 3 a 'commit') of its components.

The problem is - where to refresh it? I can't set an on-commit trigger for the view, so I have to set it on the base table - table2 (as well as to table1).
But then view1 has to be re-calculated so the refresh wouldn't help.

If I make view1 materialized as well - how do I trigger to refresh the materialized view after it finished?

What is your suggestion for such case? (PG version 11 if it matters)

Comment: Don't use a materialized view - use a regular table and triggers.

Comment: Do you mean a table just to hold the info - without constrains such as fkeys, etc.?